# Call a GUI from a JButton

Tags: java, user-interface, runtime, jbutton

I'd like to call a GUI from a swing component JButton. There will already be a GUI running at this time, but I'd like to execute another one through the use of a JButton.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S: I've tried the .show() method, and it takes over from the current GUI. This is not what I would like it to do.

Comment: You keep using that word (GUI)... I do not think it means what you think it means. When you say "GUI," do you mean a frame or some other component? When you say you would "like to execute another one" do you mean you wish to show a second frame? Would that second frame be part of the same program, or a different one?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I'm trying to build a supermarket type system which will contain several different checkouts. When the program is executed, it will bring up a user interface which the user/till operator can interact with. I'm wanting to replicate this, but have the option to add multiple checkouts, which aren't linked up. So whatever happens on checkout 1 has no effect on checkout 2 ect... To get checkout 2 up and running, I want to connect this some code which will execute a new checkout to a JButton, which will allow a second checkout to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried the .show() method

Don't use the show() method, it is deprecated. To make a window visible you use `setVisible(true)`.

> it takes over from the current GUI. This is not what I would like it to do.

Sounds like you want to prevent the child window from gaining focus. If so then the basic code you use is:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.add(...);
dialog.pack();
dialog.setFocusableWindowState( false );
dialog.setVisible( true );
```

You should use a JDialog for a child window (not a JFrame) since an application should only contain a single JFrame.

Comment: Thanks camickr! What would go into the dialog.add(...) section? :)

Comment: @MatthewLevene, the components you want displayed in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

All You need is a [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) which is here for short user interactions.

The easier way out is [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) which one overload lets you show a component.